# Sort doesn't work when user aggregation in Spring data Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I am trying run a mongo aggregation on Spring data
here is the sample json

```
{
    "id":*****
    "taskResultContent":
    [
        {
            "executionUUID":"uuid_2",
            "sequency":"1",
            "returnContent":"SUCCESS",
        },
        {
            "executionUUID":"uuid_2",
            "sequency":"2",
            "returnContent":"SUCCESS",
        }
    ]
}
```

here is my Mongo query

```
[
    {
        "$match" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54767c7cfda0da01d4843e93")
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$taskResultContent"
     },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "executionUUID" : "$taskResultContent.executionUUID",
            "returnContent" : "$taskResultContent.returnContent",
            "sequency" : "$taskResultContent.sequency",
            "_id" : 0,
            "resultID" : "$_id"
    }
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
        "executionUUID" : "uuid_3"
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort" : {
        "sequency" : -1
        }
    }
]
```

here is my java implementation:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("_id").is(objId)),
                unwind("taskResultContent"),
                project("taskResultContent.executionUUID","taskResultContent.returnContent","taskResultContent.sequency").and("resultID").previousOperation(),
                match(Criteria.where("executionUUID").is(executionUUID)),
                sort(DESC,"sequency")
            );
```

Then I found a problem, the SORT doesn't work. 
I print out the aggregation query from java. it looks like:

```
    {
        "$sort": {
            "taskResultContent.sequency": -1
        }
    }
```

it should be "sequerycy":-1 but not "taskResultContent.sequency": -1
Does anyone meet the same issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You would new class

```
class SortOperationEx implements AggregationOperation {

    private final Sort sort;

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.SortOperation} for the given {@link Sort} instance.
     *
     * @param sort must not be {@literal null}.
     */
    public SortOperationEx(Sort sort) {

        Assert.notNull(sort, "Sort must not be null!");
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public SortOperationEx (Sort.Direction direction, String... fields) {
         this(new Sort(direction, fields));
    }

    public SortOperationEx and(Sort.Direction direction, String... fields) {
        return and(new Sort(direction, fields));
    }

    public SortOperationEx and(Sort sort) {
        return new SortOperationEx(this.sort.and(sort));
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation#toDBObject(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationContext)
     */
    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {

        BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject();

        for (Sort.Order order : sort) {

            // Check reference
            String prop = order.getProperty();
            object.put(prop, order.isAscending() ? 1 : -1);
        }

        return new BasicDBObject("$sort", object);
    }
}
```

and modify code From:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("_id").is(objId)),
                unwind("taskResultContent"),
                project("taskResultContent.executionUUID","taskResultContent.returnContent","taskResultContent.sequency").and("resultID").previousOperation(),
                match(Criteria.where("executionUUID").is(executionUUID)),
                sort(DESC,"sequency")
            );
```

To:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("_id").is(objId)),
                unwind("taskResultContent"),                project("taskResultContent.executionUUID","taskResultContent.returnContent","taskResultContent.sequency").and("resultID").previousOperation(),
                match(Criteria.where("executionUUID").is(executionUUID)),
                 new SortOperationEx(DESC,"sequency")
            );
```

Comment: If you wanna sort aggregation results then - `String prop = order.getProperty();` to `String prop = order.getProperty(); prop = "_id." + prop;`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your project stage operation to use `as()` to `project` a field by some other name and then apply the sort.

```
..
project("taskResultContent.executionUUID").as("executionUUID").
and("taskResultContent.returnContent").as("returnContent")
...
```

Comment: I have tried. issue not fixed. the sort is still using  "taskResultContent.sequency": -1. I have no edit how to map it to use sequency. Your idea is to correct the alias on project. but actually the alias is correct there. but don't know why the sort is not using the alias.